# awk to insert after nth occurrence with indentation

Tags: awk, yaml, indentation

I am trying to edit a yaml file where indentation is critical. Below is the input

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 2cee4a874d2afd91d92301f15efece5afbca3abc63ba3b2b
        checksum/tls-secrets: 649c0580ebbcf3ae194d17b8ac4cc2f1cda33f145da9764
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myapp-acc
      containers:
        - name: myapp-pod
          image: "imagerepo"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 800Mi
```

And i want to insert after "resources:" which is 11th occurrence in the yaml file and "serviceAccountName:" which is the 1st occurrence in the file with respective data with indentation. By that i mean whatever indentation search pattern has we can adjust the indentation of inserting text accordingly After resources: i want

```
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 800Mi
```

After serviceAccountName

```
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: imagepullsecret
```

Output file

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 2cee4a874d2afd91d92301f15efece5afbca3abc63ba3b2b
        checksum/tls-secrets: 649c0580ebbcf3ae194d17b8ac4cc2f1cda33f145da9764
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myapp-acc
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: imagepullsecret
      containers:
        - name: myapp-pod
          image: "imagerepo"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 800Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 800Mi
```

Comment: Use `yq` for this

Comment: @anubhava yq not available on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ print }
sub(/serviceAccountName:.*/,"") && (++cnt1 == 1) {
    print $0 "imagePullSecrets:"
    print $0 "  - name: imagepullsecret"
}
sub(/resources:.*/,"") && (++cnt2 == 11) {
    print $0 "  limits:"
    print $0 "    cpu: 500m"
    print $0 "    memory: 800Mi"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 2cee4a874d2afd91d92301f15efece5afbca3abc63ba3b2b
        checksum/tls-secrets: 649c0580ebbcf3ae194d17b8ac4cc2f1cda33f145da9764
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myapp-acc
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: imagepullsecret
      containers:
        - name: myapp-pod
          image: "imagerepo"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 800Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 800Mi
```

I added the `++cnt` tests after I initially ran the code on the provide sample input since that input doesn't provide a way to test that functionality.

Comment: Thanks Ed, We are adding tabs/spaces in print, can it be modified to indent based on indent of search pattern? That way we don't have to adjust how many tabs are required while inserting.

Comment: AFAIK it already does exactly what you want as it uses whatever leading white space was present in the matching line as the initial white space for the new line, if it doesn't then edit your question to better explain your requirements.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Ed, I edited the question if it makes more sense now. About your answer did you use tab or spaces while putting in "   limits" and next 2 lines. Because i am creating this tsk.awk file in vi editor and i used tabs which worked fine for serviceAcc pattern but not for resources.

Comment: I used blanks, 2 blanks per indentation level as required after whatever indentation the matching line had just like in the example you provided.

Comment: Can we convert this into a inline awk instead of file?

Comment: Sure, call it as `awk 'script'` instead of `awk -f file_containing_script`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dedicated yaml parser such as yq for this but if you can't use it for whatever reason:

```
awk '/resources:/ { mrk=1;print;match($0,"resources:");srt=RSTART;next } mrk==1 { for(i=1;i<=srt+1;i++) { printf " " };printf "limits:\n";for(i=1;i<=srt+3;i++) { printf " " };printf "cpu: 500m\n";for(i=1;i<=srt+3;i++) { printf " " };printf "memory: 800Mi\n";mrk=0 }1' yamlfile
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/resources:/ {                                        # Process resources tag
            mrk=1;                                         # Set marker variable to 1
            print;                                         # Print line
            match($0,"resources:");                        # Find where "resources:" is in the line
            srt=RSTART;                                    # Store the location in srt variable
            next                                           # Skip to next line
            } 
     mrk==1 {                                              # Process next line after resources:
            for(i=1;i<=srt+1;i++) { 
               printf " " };                               # Use srt to print leading spaces
               printf "limits:\n";                         # Print limits tags
               for(i=1;i<=srt+3;i++) { 
                  printf " "                               # Do the same for cpu
               };
               printf "cpu: 500m\n";
               for(i=1;i<=srt+3;i++) { 
                 printf " "                                # Do the same for mem
               };
               printf "memory: 800Mi\n";
               mrk=0 
            }1' yamlfile
```

Note that this solution depends on there not being any other containers/resources in the spec which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks @Raman, will test it and get back to you, there are resources in the yaml file that's why it's the 11th occurrence. Container is once which is fine, However how can i use nth occurrence of container as well.