# Use awk to walk a tree expressed via indendation

Tags: shell, awk, tree-traversal

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
```

I would like to walk the tree with (POSIX) awk generating all paths to each key:

```
spec
spec:replicas
spec:strategy
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxSurge
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxUnavailable
spec:selector
spec:selector:matchLabels
spec:selector:matchLabels:app.kubernetes.io/name
spec:selector:matchLabels:app.kubernetes.io/instance
```

Ideally in this depth-first search pre-order ordering.

I found this related question:

[awk to insert after nth occurrence with indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114430/awk-to-insert-after-nth-occurrence-with-indentation)

But the solution is too far from what I'm after that I wasn't able to repurpose it with my pitiful knowledge of awk.

I've now written

```
match($0, /[^[:space:]]/) {
    arr[RSTART]=$1;
    for (i=1; i<RSTART; i+=1) {
        printf "%s", arr[i]
    };
    print sub(/:$/, "", arr[RSTART])
}
```

But the output is a bizarre

```
1
spec1
spec1
specstrategy1
specstrategyrollingUpdate1
specstrategyrollingUpdate1
spec1
specselector1
specselectormatchLabels1
specselectormatchLabels1
```

instead of what I was expecting. I think that's because `sub` is in-place replacement instead of outputting the new value? But I have no idea where the `1`s come from.

Comment: Is that yaml data?

Comment: [tag:yq] would be a better choice than awk to process yaml.

Comment: @Shawn by coincidence, the example in the question looks like YAML. I'd like to learn the awk so I can write commands for PlistBuddy output, formatted json; all of them are the same indent-based trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
```

then

```
awk 'match($0,/[[:alpha:]]/){arr[RSTART]=$1;for(i=1;i<RSTART;i+=1){printf "%s",arr[i]};print gensub(/:/,"",1,arr[RSTART])}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
spec
spec:replicas
spec:strategy
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxSurge
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxUnavailable
spec:selector
spec:selector:matchLabels
spec:selector:matchLabels:app.kubernetes.io/name
spec:selector:matchLabels:app.kubernetes.io/instance
```

Explanation: I use [`match` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to find position of (1st) alphabetic character, if it is found I set value in array `arr` under key being said position to 1st field, then for all values lower than position I output value from under key (not all must exists, but for non-existing `printf "%s"` is no-operation), then `print` value from under key being position with `:` removed. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes space never appears in path part AND `:` appears exactly one at end of part AND path part always starts with letter.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Re "I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task": Using text processors like `awk` will likely fail if the input isn't formatted exactly as in the sample, while still being a valid representation of the same document (as seen in your restrictive disclaimer). More examples: This approach falsely considers certain comments (try adding the line `#this is a comment`). It also includes quotes if keys used a quoting style (try changing `strategy` to `"strategy"`, which, according to the YAML specs, should represent the same value). Or "flow mappings" which can compact multiple levels into fewer lines…

Comment: What does your `gensub` do?

Comment: Why did my conversion to non-GNU get rid of the `:` delimiters and add `1` to the end of every line: `match($0,/[^[:space:]]/){arr[RSTART]=$1;for (i=1;i<RSTART;i+=1){printf "%s",arr[i] };print sub(/:$/,"",arr[RSTART])}`

Comment: @minseong [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1) does return changed `arr[RSTART]` with 1st `:` replaced using empty string i.e. deleted, `sub` does apply change in place, so you need to fist store `arr[RSTART]` in some variable, then use `sub` with target (3rd argument) being said variable, then `print` said variable

Comment: @minseong all Unix tools, including awk, have man pages. If you don't know what `gensub()` or any other awk function does you can just do `man awk` on your command line and look for `gensub()` in it's output.

Answer (score 3):

A YAML processor would give you robust results:

- Using [kislyuk/yq](https://www.github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -r 'paths | join(":")' input.yaml
```

- Using [mikefarah/yq](https://www.github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq '.* | .. | path | join(":")' input.yaml
```

Given your sample input, both output:

```
spec
spec:replicas
spec:strategy
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxSurge
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxUnavailable
spec:selector
spec:selector:matchLabels
spec:selector:matchLabels:app.kubernetes.io/name
spec:selector:matchLabels:app.kubernetes.io/instance
```

Answer (score 2):

In [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr paths.tl < data
spec
spec:replicas
spec:strategy
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxSurge
spec:strategy:rollingUpdate:maxUnavailable
spec:selector
spec:selector:matchLabels
spec:selector:matchLabels:app:kubernetes:io/name
spec:selector:matchLabels:app:kubernetes:io/instance
```

Code:

```
(let (path)
  (while-true-match-case (get-line)
    (`@{spaces #/(  )*/}@{key}:@nil`
     (let ((indent (trunc (len spaces) 2))
           (npath (spl "." key)))
       (set [path indent..:] npath)
       (put-line (join-with ":" path))))))
```